# Kotlin - Type inference in unsigned type ranges

Tags: kotlin

Why does this work (using signed types)...

```kotlin
val x = 123
println(x in Byte.MIN_VALUE..Byte.MAX_VALUE)
```

...but this doesn't (using unsigned types)...

```kotlin
val x = 123
println(x in UByte.MIN_VALUE..UByte.MAX_VALUE)
```

Error produced is:

> Type inference failed. The value of the type parameter T should be mentioned in input types (argument types, receiver type or expected type). Try to specify it explicitly.

Comment: You can't mix signed and unsigned types. Similarly, as you can't for example do: "5 + 5u`, you can't also check for signed int in the unsigned range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So `Byte.MIN_VALUE..Byte.MAX_VALUE` creates an `IntRange` (there is no `ByteRange`). And `x` is an `Int` here so it can work.

`UByte.MIN_VALUE..UByte.MAX_VALUE` returns a `UIntRange`, so you would need to declare `x` as a `UInt` type:

```
val x = 123U
```